# Annotation with User Defined class

Tags: java, annotations

While writing a simple skills system for a game, I have run into a small hiccup. My basic convention for my system uses annotations to define if a skill or ability meets all predefined requirements, but I want it to be extendable.

To do this I have implemented an Enum class with an interface and Annotated the Enums within to gather basic information. I have found that this limits my ability to create another annotation that can be placed on other classes to see if that skill needs to be "trained".

Something like:

```
public enum AthleticSkills implements AnnotatedSkill {
    @Skill(name = "Jump", base = Agility.class, trained = true)
    JUMP(public void use(){})
}
```

This enum could be any number of skill types, such as StrengthSkills, etc, all interfacing AnnotatedSkill, which does let me define the type of AnnoatedSkill within methods and parameters, but I wanted to do something similar to:

```
public @interface TrainedSkill {
    AnnotatedSkill[] value();
}
```

Trained skills are kept in a `Set<AnnotatedSkill>`.

I know this isn't possible, but I wanted to stick with the convention I have setup. I am willing to redefine how I setup skills if necessary, but if anyone has any way to make this work to keep it similar to this, I would be most greatful.

Some more explanation of how this is used:

Skills are simple, everyone will have them (think old DND skills) and everyone can use them, they use the class (Agility.class, Strength.class, etc) which are stat classes to adjust their effectiveness. Along with this there is the ability to train in a skill, a one shot, you know it or not, this is added to `Set<AnnotatedSkill>` within the player object, this just means you get additional modifiers when you use the skill.

The use() method within the ENUM can be used based on whether the trained modifier in the annotation is set, if true, it can only be used if skill is trained, if false, anyone can use it.

There is also another Annotation that can be added if you wish to limit who can train the skill (@Requirements) which can limit the training/using to classes/races/etc

I assume this would fall more into a Framework for skills/classes/races/etc.

Assume the following:

```
@Types(types = {EffectTypes.BUFF, EffectTypes.HEALTH, EffectTypes.HEAL})
@Requirements(
        abilities = {
        @RequireAbility(required = TimedHealAbility.class)})
@TrainedSkill(AthleticSkills.JUMP)
public class TimedHealEffect extends EffectComponent {}
```

This effect will only happen is they have trained AthleticSkills.JUMP, as well if they meet the requirements from @requirements.

Tracking Trained skills:

```
public class SkillTracking {
    private Set<AnnotatedSkill> trainedSkills = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<AnnotatedSkill, Boolean>());

    public void addSkill(AnnotatedSkill skill) {
        trainedSkills.add(skill);
    }

    public boolean removeSkill(AnnotatedSkill skill) {
        return trainedSkills.remove(skill);
    }

    public boolean hasSkill(AnnotatedSkill skill) {
        return trainedSkills.contains(skill);
    }
}
```

Comment: why use annotation on enum constant if it itself can keep the information necessary? something like `JUMP(Agility.class)`?

Comment: @NarendraPathai The actual annotations contains more information than just name and class, it was a idea I had to help increase the readability of the code for others when they attempt to write their own Skills. I found that adding the use method within the skill and then adding all other modifiers it got very convoluted. But I do see your point.

Comment: how are you going to assign skill set to someone? I mean how is that part of code going to work? Maybe knowing that will give me something more to form an answer. Cz right now I am confused regarding actual requirement.

Comment: @NarendraPathai I just explained some more in the question, but basicly the skills are assigned, they are available to all, unless expressly deny through the Requirements annotation... An assignment would only remove/add modifiers to the skill.

Comment: Yes I will take a look at it, but have you considered that using annotations will limit your ability to dynamically change skill set during runtime (if applicable to your requirement). Once it is coded cannot change on runtime.

Comment: @NarendraPathai the skills are ment to be simple, either you have trained them or not, and are not ment to be a major player in how the game works. I will add how to track skill assignment.